# wifi doesn't work on ubuntu

Tags: wireless, dell

I installed Ubuntu on my Dell laptop, but the wifi isn't working! I tried to solve the problem using different commands suggested by people on this forum, but none of them worked for me!

When I ran `rfkill list all` I get the following:

```
$ rfkill unblock all
$ rfkill list all
0 : dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
0 : phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
$ sudo rfkill unblock wifi      
$ rfkill list all
0 : dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
0 : phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

When I saw that there is a problem with the hardware, I checked the BIOS and everything was set correctly!

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the commands and techniques you have tried?

Comment: You don't indicate what model laptop you have, and the hard-block means the device is not turned on.  Most Dells have a keyboard switch (f2 i think) to turn on the wifi, some have a small switch on the side similar to [this image](http://wp.montvilleschools.org/it/2013/01/28/no-wireless-on-dell-latitude-e6520/)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Do you have this switch? Is it on or off? https://www.laptopmag.com/images/uploads/2730/g/dell-latitude-e6420_g9.jpg

Comment: @chili555 It does not look like a real switch since it is blocked only with the dell platform driver.

Comment: @CharlesGreen thank you so much ! that was my problem from the beginning ! thanks for everyone who tried to help me !

Answer (score 1):

Run in a terminall

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-dell.conf <<< "blacklist dell_wmi"
```

and reboot.